# Does multiple isolated OpenGL context affect performance

Tags: multithreading, opengl

My co-worker and I are working on a video rendering engine.

The whole idea is to parse a configuration file and render each frame to offscreen FBO, and then fetch the frame render results using glReadPixel for video encoding.

We tried to optimize the rendering speed by creating two threads each with an independent OpenGL context. One thread render odd frames and the other render even frames. The two threads do not share any gl resources.

The results are quite confusing. On my computer, the rendering speed increased compared to our single thread implementation, while on my partner's computer, the entire speed dropped.

I wonder here that, how do the amount of OpenGL contexts affect the overall performance. Is it really a good idea to create multiple OpenGL threads if they do not share anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Context switching is certainly not free. As pretty much always for performance related questions, it's impossible to quantify in general terms. If you want to know, you need to measure it on the system(s) you care about. It can be quite expensive.

Therefore, you add a certain amount of overhead by using multiple contexts. If that pays off depends on where your bottleneck is. If you were already GPU limited with a single CPU thread, you won't really gain anything because you can't get the GPU to do the work quicker if it was already fully loaded. Therefore you add overhead for the context switches without any gain, and make the whole thing slower.

If you were CPU limited, using multiple CPU threads can reduce your total elapsed time. If the parallelization of the CPU work combined with the added overhead for synchronization and context switches results in a net total gain again depends on your use case and the specific system. Trying both and measuring is the only good thing to do.

Based on your problem description, you might also be able to use multithreading while still sticking with a single OpenGL context, and keeping all OpenGL calls in a single thread. Instead of using `glReadPixels()` synchronously, you could have it read into PBOs (Pixel Buffer Objects), which allows you to use asynchronous reads. This decouples GPU and CPU work much better. You could also do the video encoding on a separate thread if you're not doing that yet. This approach will need some inter-thread synchronization, but it avoids using multiple contexts, while still using parallel processing to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this answer is really pointing out the way for me. The video encoding is done on separate thread. And I'm not using PBO is because my target device OpenGL version doesn't support it.

Comment: @TwilightSun: Good heavens, how old is your target device OpenGL implementation if it doesn't support PBOs? That feature is ancient stuff, supported by everything that's less than 10 years old. You may have to use an OpenGL extension, but you'll hard pressed to find an implementation that doesn't support it these days.