# How do multiple rendering contexts across multiple processes affect GPU performance?

Tags: opengl, graphics

My rendering system comprises three processes that each perform different image processing and computer graphics algorithms using the GPU. Two of the use the GPU for accelerating image processing and vision algorithms (GPGPU) and the third uses results from the other two to perform 3D rendering. Thus, they each have their own rendering context managed through the OpenGL server.

This question is very specifically about multiple rendering contexts created by different processes. Existing questions address multiple contexts in a single process. Some information about how OpenGL implementations and GPU hardware handle multiple programs and whether that rendering is truly synchronous.

How does having three different rendering contexts affect the performance of the GPU? Is it performing the draw calls of each context in serial or can multiple contexts be active on the GPU at the same time? Is there any overhead between context switching?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500450/does-multiple-isolated-opengl-context-affect-performance

Comment: Similar but doesn't quite answer all of the questions I posed.